# Replacing what looks like a 3-way with a 2-way smart switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have been installing Kasa smart switches in my house. The switches require load wires, neutral, and ground. This box is troubling me. (pictured) It looks like it’s wired for a 3-way but there is no other switch connected that I know of. How can I connect this to a 2-way smart switch?
[image]

Comment: one hot + 2 travelers. Do the travelers switch ? what happens when you disconnect one /

Comment: There may have been another 3-way switch that was removed.  If that's the case, then one of the travelers is probably no longer used.  Disconnect them one at a time a try the switch.  That will identify which traveler is still being used, which is now just a switched HOT.  And that's the one you need on the load side of you smart switch.

Comment: Once @SteveSh has written that up as an answer (hint, hint), and you've identified which is in use, be sure to put a small wire nut on the unused wire, just in case someone ever applies power to the other end of it, wherever that other end is. Also, a little label that says something to the effect of "Was a traveler for a 3-way switch" will help the next poor sucker (maybe you in 3 years) who opens up this box.

Comment: Also worth noting that Kasa makes 3-way switches, so you don't need to eliminate your 3-way circuits or wiring, you can just get a different smart switch model (HS-210) that still works with your Kasa app/ecosystem.

Comment: Note: There are 3-way and 4-way switches, a "2-way" is just called a switch. 3-way switches are used when you have 2 switches, a 4-way is needed as the middle switches whenever you have 3 or more switches controlling a single item (or group of items). Confusing I know, also this terminology is for the US, other areas of the world differ.

Answer (score 1):

Turned this from a comment into an answer ( can take a hint)...

There may have been another 3-way switch that was removed. If that's the case, then one of the travelers is probably no longer used. Disconnect them one at a time and try the switch. That will identify which traveler is still being used, which is now just a switched HOT. And that's the one you need on the load side of you smart switch.

Comment: Be sure to cap off the no-longer-in-use traveler, just in case someone discovers the other end of it and decides to apply power to it. You don't want it frying something in this box (including you). Putting a label on it indicating what it is will help future maintainers understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The wire on the black screw should be the hot that is switched between travelers,

Don’t forget sometimes the 2nd switch can be in another room or even in a different place like a garage.

Make sure to label any wires that you remove because it wouldn’t be the first time someone pulled a 3 way capped the one wire that appeared to not do anything then someone flipped the other switch months later and they couldn’t figure out what was wrong.